# matlab vectorization if statement

Tags: matlab, if-statement, vectorization

Can someone please tell me the vectorized implementation of following matlab code. Predicted is an array containing either of the two values "pos" or "neg". I have to copy the values when condition comes true.

```
    p = 1;
    box = zeros(size(bbox));


   for k = 1: size(predicted)
        if predicted(k) == 'pos'
            box(p,:) = bbox(k,:);
            p = p + 1;
        end
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bbox=rand(100); %demo data
predicted = rand(1,100)>0.5; %logical values
%You want to convert your array of strings into an array of logical values
%predicted=strcmp(predicted,'pos');
box=bbox(predicted,:);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can i do it with string as it would increase computational time for converting string to logical values.

Comment: No. A string is just a set of uint8 values, they have no meaning to a computer. An if statement requires a boolean, so you need to interpret your string. Which is what you do yourself with predicted(k) == 'pos'. Which will return [1 1 1] for 'p' 'o' 's'

Comment: `string` is a new MATLAB class. Instead of logicals, use `strcmp(predicted,"pos")` to make the logical mask. @user2033594

Comment: @TroyHaskin: Yes, as is mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Ah!  Missed that.  I have a habit of not reading comments.  Apologies.